# How Can I Update Lutris

Tags: dependencies, lutris

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and when I try to update / upgrade lutris, I always get this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lutris : Depends: gir1.2-webkit2-4.1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I searched Ubuntu Packages websites and see that `gir1.2-webkit2-4.1`:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=Gir1.2-webkit2-4.1&searchon=names&suite=kinetic&section=all

Is only available for ubuntu 22.04 or on debian.

How should I proceed?

Comment: I added an EDIT below. The version on their Github uses `gir1.2-webkit2-4.0` so there should be no dependency issues, assuming that there are no other issues with the other dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is from the [lutris-team/lutris PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elutris-team/+archive/ubuntu/lutris?field.series_filter=jammy), you should file a bug report with the maintainers. And yes, you are correct that the dependency isn't available for 20.04.

How you should proceed is kind of a matter of opinion. It depends on how bad you want to use Lutris on 20.04. You have one option of upgrading to 22.04. Alternatively, you could file a bug with the maintainers and [hold the current version to prevent automatic upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/167115) so that you can continue using a non-upgraded version of Lutirs on 20.04. If/when the bug is fixed, you could release the hold and then upgrade.

Installing `gir1.2-webkit2-4.1` on 20.04 doesn't look like a good option because there are multiple dependencies needed for `gir1.2-webkit2-4.1` that are not available on 20.04.

`gir1.2-webkit2-4.0` is available on both 20.04 and later versions like 22.04 and newer. Using this version instead of `gir1.2-webkit2-4.1` may be an option for the developers and you may want to mention this when filing the bug report.

**EDIT**

A final option would be to download and [install the deb from their github](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/releases) but you will have to manually download and install future updates. This version uses `gir1.2-webkit2-4.0` so there should be no dependency issues.

Also, you will probably have to either disable the PPA until they fix the bug or [hold the github version to prevent automatic upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/167115)
after installation (again, until they fix the bug).

Comment: Installing on 20.04 from their github with `--fix-broken` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily remove Lutris. You can install Lutris back when you make the necessary update.

```sh
sudo apt remove lutris
# ...
sudo apt install lutris
```