# Errno13: Permission denied: ‘/proc/71128/task/71128/children - Lutris cant install LeagueOfLegends

Tags: 20.04, permissions, playonlinux, lutris

I used Ubuntu 20.04LTS and user Lutris When I install League of Legends I get the following error:

```
/home/name/snap/lutris/70/.local/share/lutris/runtime/winetricks/winetricks --unattended win10
Start monitoring process.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/snap/lutris/70/usr/share/lutris/bin/lutris-wrapper”, line 202, in
main()
File “/snap/lutris/70/usr/share/lutris/bin/lutris-wrapper”, line 167, in main
if not watcher.is_alive():
File “/snap/lutris/70/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/process_watcher.py”, line 75, in is_alive
return next(self.iterate_processes(), None) is not None
File “/snap/lutris/70/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/process_watcher.py”, line 64, in iterate_processes
for child in self.iterate_children():
File “/snap/lutris/70/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/process.py”, line 131, in iter_children
for child in self.children:
File “/snap/lutris/70/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/process.py”, line 125, in children
for child_pid in self.get_children_pids_of_thread(tid):
File “/snap/lutris/70/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/process.py”, line 71, in get_children_pids_of_thread
with open(children_path, encoding=‘utf-8’) as children_file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘/proc/71128/task/71128/children’
```

Please help me solve it. Thank you very much

I tried to find a fix but it didn't work.

Comment: The dependency isn't available for 20.04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1447983/how-can-i-update-lutris